# Mockup tools for developers: balsamiq sketchflow

Tags: php, sketchflow, mockups, balsamiq

I got my first real project, but unfortunately it's with a client who doesn't quite know what he wants, which makes it a bit difficult to interact with him.

I think to help and myself, I need to introduce some prototyping or sketching tool into our conversations. I did a quick search now and found balsamiq and MS sketchflow, but I keep hearing contradicting opinions, so I need unbiased developer feedback to help me make up my mind. I'm guessing that most people who've made that decision before had to try both and probably have some insights to share.

1. I saw that MS sketchflow is interactive, but it seems balsamiq isn't. Can someone confirm?
2. Which is more flexible so I'm not stuck trying to sketch something the software doesn't allow me to sketch.
3. Which is easier to use?
4. Which is more comprehensive?
5. What other options are there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web UI prototyping tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720191/web-ui-prototyping-tools)

Comment: @Gert G, Doesn't look like a duplicate to me. The other question is general. This one mainly tries to compare 2 specific choices.

Answer (score 5):

This answer should not be considered unbiased, as I work as a developer on the SketchFlow product team at Microsoft.

SketchFlow is intended for interactive prototypes, and for gathering iterative feedback from clients/stakeholders. It has the full power of Blend behind it (which is both good and bad depending on what you are doing).

Here is a great 90 sec video that explains a bit about SketchFlow:
http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/LauraFoy/Sketchflow-in-90-seconds/

It is focused on Blend 3, but Blend 4 added many new features, including support for publishing prototypes and feedback to a Sharepoint site for easy collaboration with clients/stakeholders.

I'm happy to answer any questions you might have.

Answer (score 3):

[ForeUI](http://www.ForeUI.com/) is another option, it can create skinnable and interactive prototypes (run in web browser).  I am currently working in the ForeUI R&D team, so my suggestion may not be considered unbiased, but ForeUI is really worth trying out :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the various online collaborative mock-up applications out there, however, a quick and dirty alternative may be to have a meeting, via GoToMeeting, TeamViewer, Skype or equivalent, then open up an image editing program such as Photoshop, Fireworks, Paint, etc; and then just use one of these [stencil kits](http://speckyboy.com/2010/07/21/20-free-web-ui-element-kits-and-stencils/). Here's a [link](http://speckyboy.com/2010/04/30/iphone-and-ipad-development-gui-kits-stencils-and-icons/) to various iPhone and iPad stencils.

In this way you can pick and choose the stencils that most closely match what you're doing, or are abstract enough to not necessarily imply detail. The stencil kits usually come in a plethora of formats, allowing you to drag and drop the necessary components and create your mock-up.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

1 vote for Balsamiq

- i find that I have to think in web elements when i use it.. I find that it makes a solution crystalise as you work with it. I also find that it can also be used to polish an idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [MockupScreens](http://MockupScreens.com) (my own tool, pretty popular) and here is the list of more such tools:

http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuiPrototypingTools